# Getting an error processing archive when I try to install NodeJS LTS on Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, dpkg, node.js

I am trying to install NodeJS LTS version, actually 14.16.0, and I am getting an error processing archive like this one:

> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y (Reading database ... 415599 files
> and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
> .../nodejs_14.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking nodejs
> (14.16.0-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.21.0~dfsg-1) ... dpkg: error
> processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
> '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/packages.html', which is also in package
> nodejs-doc 12.21.0~dfsg-1 dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed
> by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.16.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb E:
> Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I already solve going to /var/cache/apt/archives apt archives and forcing to overwrite the nodejs package.

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

and then:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite 'nodejspackage.db'
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this is work!!!!

Comment: @vasper Great, don't forget to accept my answer :D